# Why don't Qt4 apps in Lubuntu pick up the GTK theme?

Tags: gtk, lubuntu, qt

I've installed Lubuntu and replaced the default players with Clementine for audio and VLC for video.

The problem I have is that neither pick up the GTK theme, the way they usually do in Gnome/Xfce. Instead they use some pretty ugly and totally off theme.

To be clear, both are Qt4 applications and should pickup the theme by default.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Install `qt4-qtconfig`, run `qtconfig` and on the first tab choose GTK+ for *Select GUI style*.

Comment: After extensive googling in the meantime, I found some Arch Linux users with the same issue, installing libgnomeui (actually in Ubuntu it's libgnomeui-0) and dependencies fixed the issue. Thanks for the answer anyway. Should this be filed as bug?

Comment: @Syanide If there's no bug report yet, then yes, that's probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

libgnomui-0 itself is not needed for the bugfix, but only one of its dependencies, libgnome2-common. And the latter does not impose any further dependencies being installed.