# Theme integration not working for various apps (Xubuntu)

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu, themes

Yesterday I posted a question about libreoffice not showing the correct theme in Xubuntu 11.10. That question was quickly answered and by installing libreoffice-gtk it now looks really nice and in line with my global theme (Ambiance for Xubuntu, found [here](http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/Ambiance+theme+for+XFCE+%28with+xfwm4%29?content=141027)).

However, I have now noticed that various other programmes are also affected. E.g. the Ubuntu Software centre, Evince, Startup Disk Creator and the Update Manager.

Is there a global solution to have these apps and programmes to show the correct theme as well (and not the ugly Windows 98 look they have now?)

I already tried the solution offered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82590/why-dont-qt4-apps-in-lubuntu-pick-up-the-gtk-theme) (installing qt-qtconfig) and [here](http://mikemcquaid.com/2011/12/make-qt-use-the-gtk-style-on-xfce-or-xubuntu/) (making script for qt programmes), but both do not work. I guess they are not qt programmes? I also installed Evince-gtk, but that didn help either (for Evince).

Comment: Ok I answered my own question. The theme I used (and which is posted on xfce-look.org) is incomplete. This causes various applications to show up without theme integration.

Comment: Do not put the answer in the question put in the answer area below and the you can accept it.

Comment: Hi Uri, I will do that. However, the system didn't yet allow me to answer my own question within 8 hours. Instead the system suggested to add info to the question. But I will put in the answer below later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have discovered what the problem was. The fault was with the chosen theme, downloaded from [xfce-look.org](http://xfce-look.org/). While it does look good in general, it is incomplete.

I suggest, if you want a good Ambience theme experience for Xubuntu, to use the latest and complete Xfce theme found on the linuxmint-art-org website. You can download that one [here](http://linuxmint-art.org/content/show.php/Ambiance+&+Radiance+Themes+for+Xfce+LXDE?content=146674&PHPSESSID=ac42d45dfad2eef8194ae3e90b36755e).

Also, for sudo-based applications (like the Synaptic package manager), be sure to add the custom theme (if you want to use one) to `/.themes` (in the root directory `/`) Otherwise they will not pick up the theme.

Comment: The directory for sudo-based applications should probably be `/root/.themes` (not `/.themes`).