# How do I fix the problems I'm having with Xfce and Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, gtk, battery, xfce, gtk3

I booted into a Xubuntu session and when the splash disappeared it left behind artifacts on the desktop.  I went into Desktop to change the background but it stayed completely gray.  Not only that, GTK isn't theming any of my windows, nor can I change GTK themes in the settings manager.  I recently installed GTK+ 2.x alongside GTK+ 3 for a compatibility issue with xfce-battery-plugin, which also refuses to show anything but 0%.  What is going on?

Comment: How did you install `xfce` ? xfce has components like `xfdesktop`, `xfwm`, for battery install `xfce4-power-manager`. Are those all installed ?

Comment: It looks like a borked installation. Your best bet might be a clean re-installation.

Comment: It was the stock xfce that came with my xubuntu installation, all those components were installed as well.  Well xfce4-power manager is already installed, so that's not the issue...I don't get it, I've reinstalled twice already...ugh.  Will removing GTK+ 2.x solve the GTK issue at least?  That's really bugging me, the battery issue not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, reinstalled Xubuntu, the built-in battery monitor still doesn't work.  Rhythmbox is also not picking up my GTK theme, but fortunately everything else is.  Thanks for your help with the previous problem, now what do you propose I do about the above issues?

Comment: Well I tried that, putting .themes in the root directory, no dice. Is it /root/.themes or /.themes or what?  I tried those and they haven't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the GTK+ theme integration, I was having some issues with this as well (I use a custom theme). I posted about the problem, and the various solutions, [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86391/theme-integration-not-working-for-various-apps-xubuntu/86552#86552). Hope it helps you!