# Gtk theme change doesn't apply to kde apps?

Tags: themes

I changed the systemwide ambiance theme a bit (specifically the scrollbar css), and this works fine in gtk apps, but in kde apps nothing has changed. They still have the vanilla ambiance look. I tried rebooting too.

Btw I've disabled overlay scrollbars.

I looked at this question: [Why don't Qt4 apps in Lubuntu pick up the GTK theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82590/why-dont-qt4-apps-in-lubuntu-pick-up-the-gtk-theme) and tried setting the Gtk+ theme in qtconfig but that didn't help. The look remains the same. Changing the theme in qtconfig to another one, such as QtCurve, does have an effect though.

Answer (score 0):

Since QT and GTK are two distinct toolkits to create GUIs, what applies to the first doesn't necessarily apply to the last, and vice versa. GTK+ themes apply to applications that are built using the GTK+ toolkit, and the QT themes apply only to apps built using the QT framework. Unless an application is compatible with GTK, it won't adopt a GTK theme. What qtconfig does is imitate GTK themes in the QT framework.It still can't apply properly the GTK theme to a QT item. As for why it didn't work, are you sure you have the proper qtconfig? There are two, one for QT 3 and another for Qt 4. for KDE 4 apps you need the latter. I've changed the QT themes from qtconfig to GTK+ and they did change but they still look fake and don't have the GTK touch to them.